How to Include Firebase Dependencies Only for a Specific Product Flavor in Android and Exclude Them Completely for Others?
Primarily, I want to clarify that this isn't a duplicate. I've gone through every question on Stack Overflow that has a similar topic but couldn't find a solution. I've also gone through the documentation, which doesn't specifically mention this issue.
I'm trying to build APKs for both GitHub and F-Droid releases. I want to exclude everything related to Google services in the F-Droid builds. I've implemented two flavors of this project: fdroid for F-Droid builds and github for GitHub builds.
To include the Gradle dependencies at the app level, I've modified the build.gradle file at the app level as follows:
var flavourName = ""
android {
...
    flavorDimensions = ["distribution"]
        productFlavors {
            fdroid {
                dimension "distribution"
                flavour = "fdroid"
            }
            github {
                dimension "distribution"
                flavour = "github"
            }
        }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    githubImplementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.2')
    githubImplementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    githubImplementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}

if (flavourName == "github") {
    plugins.apply("com.google.gms.google-services")
    plugins.apply("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
}

This works as expected when targeting the GitHub builds, but as soon as I switch to the F-Droid build, it throws an error saying:
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: File google-services.json is missing. 
The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.


I'm aware of why this occurs. This isn't an issue in the github build because I've added the Google services file in the GitHub-specific flavored module, so it works as expected.

The current project structure looks like:

The reason this issue occurs when targeting the F-Droid build is that the Google services and Crashlytics plugins' classpaths still exist in the root-level Gradle file.
How can I fix this issue?

One of the solutions I came across involved modifying it to work at compile time to suit my needs. I've added this in the app-level Gradle file:

beforeEvaluate {
    if (flavour == "github") {
        buildscript {
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
            }
        }
        plugins {
            id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.2' apply false
            id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '3.0.2' apply false
        }
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
        apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    }
}


This works for F-Droid builds at both compile and runtime, but for GitHub builds, although it works at compile time, the moment the app launches, it throws:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when the Crashlytics Gradle plugin is missing from your app's build configuration.


I went through a few answers on Stack Overflow, which suggest adding:
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:x.x.x' In the project root build.gradle, which I don't want in this case because I'm targeting two different builds, with one of them not containing anything related to Google services or Firebase.

I want no presence of Google services or Firebase in F-Droid builds, but want them included in GitHub builds, i.e., Google services and Firebase should not exist in F-Droid builds, but should be present in GitHub builds.
How can I solve this?
